# Not sure how to fix the 'numerical expression has 41 elements: only the first used' warning

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Currently trying to write functions to compute assurance benefits and reserves/ policy values although when trying to plot, keep getting the same error and am pretty lost at to how I solve it. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#Annuity-due function
AnU = function(x, n, i)
{
  An = 0
  for (k in 0:(n-1))
  {
    An = An + (1/(1+i))^k*lx[x+k]/lx[x]
  }
  return(An)
}

#Term/whole life assurance function
TWa <- function(x, n, i){
  if (missing(n)) 
    n = 120 - x - 1
  Ta = 0
  for(k in 0:(n-1))
  {
      Ta = Ta + (1/(1+i))^(k+1)*(lx[x+k]-lx[x+k+1])/lx[x]
  }
    return(Ta)
}
#Setting Premium
P <- 100000*TWa(x = 25, n = 40, i = 0.04)/AnU(x = 25, n = 40, i = 0.04)

#Policy value function
age <- c(1:120)
term <- c(1:120)
time <- c(1:120)
policy_TW <- function(time, age, term, rate)
  return(100000*TWa(x = age + time, n = term - time, i = rate) -
    P * AnU(x = age + time, n = term - time, i = rate))
for (time in 0:40)
  cat("At time", time, " policy value is ", policy_TW(time, 25, 40, 0.04), "\n")

#Plot
plot(0:40, policy_TW(0:40, 25, 40, 0.04), ylim = c(0,6000), type = "b")

> plot(0:40, policy_TW(0:40, 25, 40, 0.04), ylim = c(0,6000), type = "b")
Warning messages:
1: In 0:(n - 1) :
  numerical expression has 41 elements: only the first used
2: In 0:(n - 1) :
  numerical expression has 41 elements: only the first used
```

Edit: For purpose of reproducibility, I forgot to add the `lx` code.
This has been calculated from the linked xls file which is then named `data`
https://www.actuaries.org.uk/documents/am92-permanent-assurances-males

```
# Calculate the values for lx
qx = c(rep(NA,16),data$qx)
lx = vector()
lx[1:17] = c(rep(NA,16),10000)
for (i in 18:120)
{
  lx[i]=lx[i-1]*(1-qx[i-1])
}
```

Comment: Thanks for making that edit. But it still doesn't quite fit the standards for a reproducible example because there is no code included for someone here to easily get the object called `data` in their environment without going to an external link. If I were you in the future I would explicitly include some values in your code in place of where it now says `data$qx`. Then people can just run this code without having to download any data. The goal is to have people be able to reproduce your error and help you, with minimal effort on their part to set it up on their local machine.

Comment: Ahhh, that makes a lot of sense to be fair. I'll be sure to keep that in mind for future questions. The help has been much appreciated, my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `0:(n-1)` creates a sequence, a single vector of integers going from zero to `n-1`. However your `n` is itself a vector, because it is defined as `term - time` and `time` is a vector of all integers 0 to 40 (hence it contains 41 elements). So only the first element of `n` is used to create the sequence. For example if `n` was `c(4,5,10)`, only the 4 would be used, ignoring 5 and 10, and `0:(n-1)` would return `c(0,1,2,3)`.

You would need to redefine the `AnU()` and `TWa()` functions. I am not sure exactly what you need but I think you can just replace the line `for (k in 0:(n-1))` with `for (k in 0:(max(n)-1))`. I wanted to test this but I was unable to reproduce your error because the object `lx`, which is in the formula in both functions, is not defined in your code.

Comment: That's cleared a lot up, many thanks.
The change you recommended has sorted the warning, which is great! Totally forgot to include the ```lx``` object - my apologies there

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! If this answer solves your problem please upvote and/or accept it.

Comment: Another tip: for future reference if a mistake such as forgetting to include `lx` is in your question you can edit the question to fix that. That might be helpful to do in case other people look at this question later and want to reproduce your code.